# How can a site have the domain name www.com?

Tags: networking, dns, nameserver

I noticed that www.com is a valid domain name.

Is this because the .com nameserver has an IP registered for the name www, and therefore its a valid domain name? If so, what is the purpose of the www prefix in a URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/145777/what-s-the-point-in-having-www-in-a-url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual characters of the URL are arbitrary, and refer to a particular address found by looking up the URL in the [domain name system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) (DNS) from a server (or from the *hosts* file on your own PC). "www." was just a prefix to distinguish between the "web" (sites using HTML that can be displayed in browsers) and FTP, UDP, mail etc. [Today's standards expect web sites to be addressable both with and without a prefix.](https://www.sitepoint.com/domain-www-or-no-www/)

As far as "legal" names, the list of domains (last characters in the URL) has been greatly increased. The original list was *[.com, .org, .net, .int, .edu, .gov, .mil and .arpa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains)*, where *.arpa* referred to the defense agency that supported the web as a fault-tolerant communication mechanism.

So *www.com* is simply a valid name that [Uniregistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniregistry) is sitting on... probably waiting for the right price. Incidentally, because the initial *www.* can be ignored, *www.www.www.com* arrives at the same destination.

BTW, the URL *www.org* is a valid alias for *https://www.w3.org/*, the World Wide Web Consortium that helps set web standards.

Comment: "_list of domains_" -> TLDs, or Top-Level Domains

Comment: Also, I'm not sure where you're going with "_because the initial www can be ignored_"... that is not true, and it's likely that `www.com` is registered with a wildcard subdomain (`yyy.www.com` forwards to `www.com` too). Browsers are forwarded to `www.com` by an HTTP header, which is a whole technology on top of plain DNS.

Comment: Note also the constraints imposed by DNS, as answered here: https://serverfault.com/a/145781/405400

Comment: @Attie: yes, TLD is the same "list". "www." can be removed by the server, as shown in the reference above, https://www.sitepoint.com/domain-www-or-no-www/